# Meteor OR condition not working in template file

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use or condition in the template file, If any variable is true from these 3 then the condition should run but it's not working.

In template file this is my condition

```
{{#if imagesP videoP allImg }}
<div class="my-cls" id="img1">

</div>
{{/if}}
```

In global file, I have registered helper

```
UI.registerHelper('or', function(a, b, c) {
    return a || b || c;
});
```

Comment: First, I would recommend to use `Template.registerHelper` instead. Then please add the erros that have been returned or your debugging results. What were the vlaues for a,b and c and what was the return value.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement doesn't rely on your helper for evaluation.

try this for instance:

```
{{#if (or imagesP videoP allImg) }}
<div class="my-cls" id="img1">

</div>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: It's showing "unexpected template close error" becaues in your code we did not start {{#if}} just close {{/if}}.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry you right. I'mma edit this answer now.

Comment: it's still not going into condition

Comment: hmm, have you checked your helper definition? What's meant by `UI`? Global helpers are defined by using `Template` keyword like so:
`Template.registerHelper('getGreetings',function(){
   let greetings = "hello world";
   return greetings;
})
`

Comment: You may also want to check if the file where you defined your helper is properly imported or there are actual values being passed to your helper in the HTML file.

Comment: I had tried already using Template.registerHelper but it's not working. Values of all 3 variables are coming in helper when i am using console.log(). One more thing if there are no value in any variable e.g. in "a" then it's showing undefined for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193814/discussion-between-harry-adel-and-user3714488).